# Burninate the tag [safe]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The tags [safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/safe) and [safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/safety) sound somewhat useless to me. I think they should either be burninated or merged into [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security).

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't sound safe to me. Oh well, who cares? Maybe a partial marge might be in order, as some of the posts look quite decent?

Comment: Safe is abundant in context. I mean, who would possibly be looking for unsafe code?

Comment: Note that there are various more specific tags such as [tag:thread-safety], [tag:safety-critical], [tag:type-safety], [tag:memory-safety]. I note that [tag:safe] and [tag:safety] have no tag wiki entries.

Comment: @Unihedron People who use c#, where unsafe is a keyword applied to blocks of code :p? (It means "this block is allowed to twiddle pointers a la c++".) </needlessly pedantic>

Comment: @thenaglecode burninate is a technical term on meta, in case you didn't know.

Comment: @TimSequine, after browsing meta for a while. I too have come to this plagaritismic conclusion.

Comment: TROGDOOOOORRRR Burning all the safety referencesssssss!!!!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somehow, seeing [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) in the top of the related lists for both [safe] and [safety] wasn't all that surprising.

[image: Burned]

Please [care for the widows and orphans](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/untagged).

Answer (score 17):

Neither of those tags has a tag wiki entry, which is one piece of evidence that suggests that nobody cares much about them.

There are various more specific tags such as [thread-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread-safety), [safety-critical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/safety-critical), [type-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-safety), [memory-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-safety), which means that the generic [safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/safety) could be burninated without losing those specific and useful meanings.

Safety and security are not the same thing, so I'd argue against merging them. For example, code can be thread-safe and type-safe whilst being totally insecure. It can be very secure (in the sense of confidentiality) whilst not being safety-critical (e.g. it crashes if any intrusion is detected).

Answer (score 15):

Many of the questions tagged [safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/safe) look like the user wrote a *phrase* in the tags box, such as "php safe string" or "apache safe multithreading".  This is a common problem; new users often don't understand that tags are supposed to be independent of each other.